# Typeahead.js event fired when emptyed

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I have Typahead.js plagind and want to set `data-id` attribute to `''` when input field is empty. Now I'm using it to set `data-id` when specific suggestion is selected, but when it is empty can't catch an event.

```
typeaheadFields.bind('typeahead:select', function (ev, suggestion) {
    $(this).parent().find('.attribute-slider-category-id').attr('data-id', suggestion.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with this:

```
typeaheadFields.keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).parent().find('.attribute-slider-category-id').attr('data-id', '');
            }
        });
```